# Testing responsive without mobile device

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm working on making my site more responsive.  If I decrease my browser width to its minimal width, is this a good substitute for testing what will happen on mobile devices?

I don't have devices such as the iPad Mini or Galaxy S2/3 but still want to make sure the site will look good on them.

Comment: If you are using media queries, then yes just resize your browser.

Comment: Yes - I'm using them.  Post as answer and I'll accept.

Comment: You *can* download mobile emulators.  Android SDK can emulate pretty much any version of Android.  I'm a big fan of the Opera mobile emulator because its not sluggish like the Android emulator.  Sometimes its not just the *size* that needs to be tested, but functionality.

Comment: @cimmanon - emulators are usually way off.

Comment: @Omega - sorry I didn't see the flood of other answers.  stackoverflow has a new thing now that you have to click to see them.

Comment: They're no worse than simply resizing your browser in this particular instance.  Short of getting multiple physical devices, emulators are the next best thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using media queries, then yes just resize your browser. You can keep an eye on the window size by using an inspection tool like firebug and checking the body width.

Answer (score 4):

`Ctrl + Shift + M` on Firefox(Windows)

`Cmd + Option + M` on Firefox(Mac)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test your designs locally, in the browser, you can use Web Developer Add-On which will give you an option to view responsive layouts

[image]

Also you get ton's of online website out there which will do the job for you like

- http://mattkersley.com/responsive/
- http://www.studiopress.com/responsive/
- http://www.responsivedesigntest.net/
- http://screenqueri.es/

Answer (score 1):

CHECK Responsinator: Help you to test site on different devices and different orientations

http://www.responsinator.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest finding browser plugins that allow you to resize your browser to specific browser dimensions. Then set up the common sizes using it...320px, 480px, 600px, etc, and/or whatever needed for your project.

For Chrome, I use Window Resizer.

Answer (score 0):

I use your described method myself, it is not 100% accurate, some textual sizes could change slightly especially if you are using em or rems.  If testing box layout and stuff like that it can be fairly accurate.

Another solution would be to use a service like http://quirktools.com/screenfly is a relatively good solution also.

The best solution that I also use is Browser Stack: http://www.browserstack.com/  It is not free however.  Browser Stack also allows you to test different operating systems, different browsers, and a multitude of different mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go is with the devices, but, if some or all the devices are not available then you will have to resort to some other ( good ) tools out there. Here are a few examples :

- [Testing Tool 1](http://mattkersley.com/responsive/)
- [Testing Tool 2](http://www.responsivedesigntest.net/)

Keep in mind, these sort of tools will show you pixel perfect output and the user interaction/behaviors maybe different.